# Quelle serait une façon plus concise, plus simple, plus claire de formuler l’idée ci-après?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Les exemples manquaient de rigueur, une formule présentée était fausse mais hormis ces imprécisions la quintessence de la réponse était correcte (le fond, le plus important répondait correctement à la question).

Merci.

Comment: Je suppose que c'est pour des enfants? En général ça va, peut-être juste trouver un synonyme de quintessence puisque c'est un mot plus poussé, "l'essentiel" peut-être?

Comment: Comment peut-il avoir des exemples qui manquent de rigueur, une fausse formule mais en même temps avoir une quintessence qui répond correctement à la question? C'est une fleur à l'élève?

Comment: Eh bien tout simplement le paragraphe (l’essentiel), y compris les explications, qui introduit lesdits exemples et la formule fausse imputable à l’oubli d’une variable…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu ne peux pas qualifier une erreur d'imprécision et "quintessence" est trop soutenu et inadapté ici.

> Les exemples manquaient de rigueur, une formule présentée était fausse mais [en dehors de ces points,] l'essentiel de la réponse était correct.

Comment: On peut même enlever "en dehors de ces points" pour plus concis.

Comment: @Simon Très juste, je prends !

Comment: Réponse excellente, comme toujours!

Answer (score 0):

Il semble y a voir très peu à modifier dans cette formulation ; elle est suffisamment claire. Il n'y a que la forme du contenu de la parenthèse qui n'est pas bien conçu. On suppose que l'interprétation est que  le fond est ce qu'il y a de plus important ; alors il faut une virgule pour marquer l'apposition.

- Les exemples manquaient de rigueur, une formule présentée était fausse mais hormis ces imprécisions la quintessence de la réponse était correcte (le fond, le plus important, répondait correctement à la question).